# Adding Labels to buttons

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'd like to label the buttons (UIBarButtonItem) on my UIToolbar because I'm going to be using custom icons that may not be 100% obvious/intuitive without them.  Having a hard time figuring out the best way to do this.

Given that buttons center themselves vertically on the toolbar there's not really enough space to drop a label below them so I'm wondering if I can get away with putting a toolbar at the bottom of the screen (to give me room for labels) and then adding a second toolbar just slightly above that, overlapping the first, where I can add my buttons. (I'm assuming that I can tweak the colors of the bottom bar so it doesn't look quite as ugly).

Is this okay?  A terrible idea?  Is there some other way to accomplish this?

(Related, incidentally, to this thread too:  [How did I get this with Interface Builder (and is it 'legal')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554641/how-did-i-get-this-with-interface-builder-and-is-it-legal))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend you do that, it's probably against the HIG, and it won't look that great.

If your buttons aren't too obvious, you can display a popover when the user first opens that screen that explains what button does what. You can also put a small help icon that displays that popover again.

Additionally, I think you can use buttons with text instead of an icon, but using both kinda defeats the purpose of the icon.